# Insert comments for a post through Blogger API v3.0

Tags: javascript, json, rest, api, blogger

Available methods in Blogger API v3.0 for 'comments' are as following

**list**

Retrieves the list of comments for a post.

**get**

Retrieves one comment resource by its commentId.

**approve**

Marks a comment as not spam.

**delete**

Delete a comment by ID.

**listByBlog**

Retrieves the comments for a blog, across all posts, possibly filtered.

**markAsSpam**

Marks a comment as spam. This will set the status of the comment to spam, and hide it in the default comment rendering.

> How can i insert comments for a post through Blogger API v3.0?

Comment: Haven't tested, but might be possible to do. This used to be possible in v2.0 (https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#CreatingComments) but that API has been replaced by v3.0 (https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/directory) but v2.0 hasn't been shut down yet

Comment: Yes. Creating comments option is available in API v2.0. I could not find in v3.0

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same problem, so I created an xml way to insert comments, take a look.
[NODE JS solution](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blogger_auth)

```
const { google } = require('googleapis')
const axios = require('axios')
const redirectUri = 'https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground'

async function endRequest(data){
  try {
    return data.status 
  } catch (error) {
    return error 
  }
}

async function send(dataAuth){     
    var oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(dataAuth.clientId, dataAuth.clientSecret, redirectUri)
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials({refresh_token : dataAuth.refreshToken})
    var accessToken = oAuth2Client.getAccessToken()
    var endPoint = `https://www.blogger.com/feeds/${dataAuth.bloggerId}/${dataAuth.postId}/comments/default`

    var requestBody = "<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'>\n" +
                         `<content type=\"html\">${dataAuth.replaceString}</content>\n` +
                      "</entry>"

      let axiosConfiguration = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/atom+xml',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${(await accessToken).token}`
        }
      }
            
     return axios.post(endPoint, requestBody, axiosConfiguration)
        .then((res) =>  endRequest(res))
        .catch((err) =>  endRequest(err))
}

module.exports = {send}
```